# Any index/parameter to evaluate std error and std deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error

I saw there are tons of good questions on standard error y deviation.
I read many of them and I think I got the point. However I am still not sure that showing one over the other is correct. Unless that std error equals std desv.
My question is: Is any parameter relating std error and deviation so one can valorate the quality of the study?

Sorry if the uestion has been asked or if it is not clear.

Comment: I would say that a standard error is a standard deviation (or square root of the variance) of the distribution of an estimator rather than of the data.  For example the standard error of the mean is based on the distribution of the estimator of the population mean, even though you only see the data once and so only have one estimate of the mean.